# Why do Lorentz invariance and Ward identities imply the structure $\Pi(k^2)(k^2\eta^{\mu\nu}-k^{\mu}k^{\nu})$ for the photon self energy?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-electrodynamics, ward-identity

In the first page of [this](http://bolvan.ph.utexas.edu/~vadim/Classes/2012f/chargeren.pdf) link we can read that Ward identities and Lorentz invariance make the form if the photon self-energy be

$$\Sigma^{\mu\nu}=\Pi(k^2)(k^2\eta^{\mu\nu}-k^{\mu}k^{\nu}).$$

Why?

Comment: The tensor structure follows from $\eta^{\mu\nu}$ and $k^\mu k^\nu$ being the only available tensors as in [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137577/50583). Is your question something else or is this a sufficient duplicate?

Comment: Isn't the relevant Ward identity, $k_\mu  \Sigma^{\mu\nu} = 0$?

Comment: @ACuriousMind and how do you know that $\eta^{\mu\nu}$ and $k^{\mu}k^{\nu}$ are the only available tensors?

Comment: @innisfree yes it is

Comment: Well, the only objects available are the metric and the momentum vector. The only way to get a 2-tensor out of the momentum is $k^\mu k^\nu$. There just isn't anything else.